# Comparing two lists to find the average

Tags: python, python-3.x

The list should hold the average profit of all januaries and all februaries etc;
The way I thought you could do this was to compare to lists, such as year 1 list would have value for janurary, feb, march,...,december and from there I could find the average profit based on the years, This hasn't been working and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

```
MONTHS = 12
def average_profit(years):
    assert years >= 0, "Years cannot be negative"
    total = 0.0
    monthly_average = 0.0
    total_months = years * MONTHS
    total_list = []
    average_list=[]
    percentage_list = []
    for i in range(0, years):
        yearly_total = 0.0
        for j in range(1, 13):
            monthly_profit = float(input("Please enter the profit made in month {0}: ".format(j)).strip())
            monthly_average = monthly_average + monthly_profit
            month_average = monthly_average/j
            total_list.append(monthly_profit)
            average_list.append(month_average)
            yearly_total = yearly_total + monthly_profit
            total_percent = (monthly_profit/12)*100
            percentage_list.append(total_percent)
        print("Total this year was ${0:.2f}".format(yearly_total))
        total = total + yearly_total
    average_per_month = total / total_months
    return total, average_per_month, total_months, total_list, average_list,          percentage_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that `for i in range(0, years)` should be changed to `for i in range(0, years)`. You do this right with the months, but getting it right with the years is just as important.

Comment: seems like the two things are the same..?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a better data structure could help with this a good bit.  It's hard to tell what your best bet will be, but one suggestion could be to use a `dict` (`defaultdict` is even easier):

```
from collections import defaultdict:
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(0,years):
    for month in range(1,13)
        d[month].append(float(input()))

#now find the sum for each month:
for i in range(1,13):
    print sum(d[i])/len(d[i])
```

Of course, we could use a list instead of a dictionary, but the dictionary would allow you to use month names instead of numbers (which may be kind of nice -- and I bet you could get their names pretty easily from the `calendar` module.)